# java не работает

Tags: java

java перестала исполнять файлы, и вообще делать что-либо, при двойном щелчке по исполняемому jar файлу открывается cmd на момент, и сразу закрывается, java --version перестала отображать версию, после команды пропуск и всё, ошибки не выдает при этом, при попытке запустить сервер майна просто открывается командная строка, и ничего не происходит
*команда java --version:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*командная строка при попытке запуска сервера:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

переустанавливать пробовал, изначально была jdk, и все работало буквально вчера, выключил комп на ночь, и перестало работать, попробовал поставить jre, то же самое, более старая jdk(17) то же самое

Comment: Причины могут быть различные, вероятно, следует для начала проверить переменные окружения `PATH` и/или `JAVA_HOME` -- содержат ли они корректный путь к JDK / JRE.  Также нужно будет проверить целостность данных на диске (HDD/SDD), где установлена Java.  Если обнаружатся битые участки, то можно попытаться переустановить её на другой диск/раздел.

Comment: если бы была проблема с PATH или JAVA_HOME, то при команде java --version в командной строке писалось бы что java не является исполняемой командой, выдавало бы хоть какую-то ошибку, а так она как буд-то бы исполняет команду, но результата нет

Comment: Почему?  Можно создать какой-то пустой исполняемый файл `java.bat` (или файл с пустым выводом), и подставить его в путь `PATH`.  Система будет запускать именно этот фальшивый файл, а не (условно) требуемый `java.exe`

Answer (score 3):

**Стоит проверить и подчистить за старым инсталлером.**

Новые установщики зачастили мусорить в систему.
`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java` ставят себя в папку `javapath` в виде симлинков на папку `C:\Program Files\Java\%ВЕРСИЯ%\bin`.

Скачать JRE или JDK, установить и прописать переменные окружения.

А именно, `PATH` на `C:\Program Files\Java\%ВЕРСИЯ%\bin` и `JAVA_PATH` на `C:\Program Files\Java\%ВЕРСИЯ%`, а также проверить и убрать из `PATH` ссылку на  `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

**Починить реестр**

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar]
@="jarfile"
```

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\%ВЕРСИЯ%\\bin\\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%1\" %*"
```

P.S. Как менять переменные окружения.

```
rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

или кнопка `Environment Variables` в закладке `Advanced`

```
control.exe sysdm.cpl ,3
```